# Capturing output/redirection of commands chained by &&

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I have a series of commands a,b,c which I am chaining together with &&: `a && b && c`.

I want to catch the output of all the commands to both stdout and stderr.
`a && b && c 2>&1 > capture_file`  only captures the output from the c command.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
{ a && b && c; } >capture_file 2>&1
```

Note the order of redirections: you have to redirect stdout first.

Comment: Why stdout first?

Comment: @TLOlczyk `2>&1` means duplicating the destination of stdout(1) to stderr(2), so it would be useless unless you've set up stdout redirection beforehand.

Comment: @TLOlczyk It doesn't _have_ to be stdout first - you could do stderr first: `2>capture_file >&2` (but don't, because that's not idiomatic).  The important thing is that you redirect one of them to file before duplicating that stream to the other.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from using command grouping `{}` you can also run the commands in a subshell and capture the output (and/or error) at once :

```
( a && b && c ) >file.txt 2>&1
```

Example :

```
$ ( echo foo && echo bar && echo baz && echos foo ) >check 2>&1

$ cat check
foo
bar
baz
No command 'echos' found, did you mean:
 Command 'echo' from package 'coreutils' (main)
echos: command not found
```